# Как избавится от ошибки в консоли браузера и корректно обработать ответ сервера?

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу разобраться, как в JS сделать что то типа
`Если переменная существует, то: //some code`
Я получаю ответ от сервера, и хочу обработать его примерно таким образом. Но, во первых, если   `response.uploadFiles.errorMessage` не существует в ответе сервера, то выполнение ajax запроса просто подвисает, и в консоль выдается ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorMessage' of undefined`
А во вторых, даже если проверка на undefined выполняется, то в переменную `serverMessage` все равно записывается `undefined`

```
 success: function (response) {
        if (response.pdo['commit'] == true) {
            //some code
        } else {
            var serverMessage ='';
            if (typeof(response.message.errorMessage) !== undefined) {
                serverMessage += response.message.errorMessage;
            }
            if (typeof(response.uploadFiles.errorMessage) !== undefined) {
                serverMessage += response.uploadFiles.errorMessage;
            }
            if (typeof(response.pdo.errorMessage)!== undefined) {
                serverMessage += response.pdo.errorMessage;
            }

            $('#serverResponse').text(serverMessage).fadeIn(500);
        }
```

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorMessage' of undefined_ - текст ошибки говорит не то, что `errorMessage` === `undefined`, а то, что **объект у которого** это свойство берется - `undefined`.

Comment: @Grundy, получается мне нужно сделать две проверки? типа
`if (typeof(response.uploadFiles) !== undefined) {
     if (typeof(response.uploadFiles.errorMessage) !== undefined) {
         serverMessage += response.uploadFiles.errorMessage;
     }`  
Как то очень громоздко получается. А если у мне нужно достучатся например до  response.object1.a.b.c.?

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, вы должны добавить еще одну проверку. Сократить можно, если убрать `typeof`.

Comment: _А если у мне нужно достучатся например до response.object1.a.b.c._ - тогда нужно проверить каждый элемент